# angular Big.js integration get the type

Tags: angular, typescript

In the app where I'm working I've to
use Big.js 
To integrate it I followed this steps

1) create a typings.d.ts with

```
declare module '*.mjs';
```

2) Create a provider

```
import Big from 'big.js/big.mjs';
{ provide: 'BigJs', useValue: Big },
```

3) Create a service

import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
@Injectable()
export class BigjsService {
  readonly TO_FIXED = 2;
  constructor(@Inject('BigJs') private bj: any) {}

  toStr(num: number | string): string {
    return this.bj(num).toFixed(this.TO_FIXED);
  }

  op(num: number | string): any {
    return this.bj(num);
  }
}
```

Now I want to type Big in the service
what's the right way ?

I thought like

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import Big from 'big.js/big.mjs';
type MyBig = typeof Big;

@Injectable()
export class BigjsService {
  readonly TO_FIXED = 2;
  constructor(@Inject('BigJs') private bj: MyBig) {}

  toStr(num: number | string): string {
    return this.bj(num).toFixed(this.TO_FIXED);
  }

  op(num: number | string): MyBig {
    return this.bj(num);
  }
}
```

Is it the right way ?

**It works but since the service is imported
a lot of times I'm afraid that big.mjs was imported
a lot of times too :(**